# Get the CPU temperature on poky linux

Tags: linux, embedded, temperature

I'm monitoring the performance of an ARM-based embedded device which runs **`poky`** linux distro (from Yocto project) which contains OpenEmbedded build system. I need to get the CPU temperature time and again. Without having to depend on third-party programs, is there a way I can get the CPU temperature? Is there a system file that I can read to get this information?

Answer (score 5):

The old way to get CPU temperature was in `/proc` through `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/ATF0/temperature`, but this has been deprecated.

CPU temperature can now be found here: `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`

Note: The units is one thousandths of a degree C. So `33500 = 33.5 C`.

Comment: The above paths don't exist in the `poky` distro that I'm using! Any other way to get this info?